# virtual host for an app and a website, access website in port 80 and app 81?

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I have a website X and an app Y.
They have nothing in common.

I'd like my users to access my website: www.example.com
**and in my android app I will add the ip:81**. users will not see the url anyway.

I already have a dir for my website and it is working, so I'd not like to chance anything. \www\html

**I just created \www\html2 for the app.**

my apache httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

If I create another conf file and add:

app.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html2"
    ServerName site2
</VirtualHost>
```

will it work or do I need to change something else? So I can access ip:81? and my website will stay normal?

Answer (score 0):

Add Listen entry in app.conf

```
Listen 81
```